# Showing a dynamic json on a wpf grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a Json that looks something like this:

```
{
  "Rows": [
    {
      "Revision": "B",
      "Descriptor": "Testitem [Rev:B]",
      "Columns": {
        "isOnFire": "true",
        "Titel": "sdjfh",
      },
      "IsFileReleased": false,
      "Quantity": 3.0,
      "Position": "1",
      "DmsId": 0,
      "WsId": 0
    },
    {
      "Revision": "F",
      "Descriptor": "Testitem [Rev:F]",
      "Columns": {
        "isOnFire": "true",
        "Titel": "sadasdwwww"
      },
      "IsFileReleased": false,
      "Quantity": 2.0,
      "Position": "2.1",
      "DmsId": 0,
      "WsId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

This can be serialized to an object. The problem is the columns are dynamic so I used:

```
public class Columns
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _extraStuff;
}
```

to serialize this part. Which works fine. When I now show this on a wpf datagrid all columns get created but columns should not be shown, rather the properties inside should also show.
How can I achieve that?

The datagrid.ItemsSource is set in code and not with a binding.

[Datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPrlZ.png)

Comment: Simplest would be to create a datatable matches the json you get. Translate the data into that. Bind the defalt view of the datatable to itemssource of your datagrid.

Comment: That did work great. A datatable displays just fine.